# Multidomain ROR application with conditions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, data-structures

I'm making a profession listing application where I will have multiple domains like for example foo-listing.com / bar-listing.com, where professions foo and bar will have there own properties in the database.

Also a professional can be linked to foo and bar and must be appear on both websites. For the moment I have 2 solutions in my head :

- I make 2 apps that will use the same database
- I make 1 app where I list the professions based on the url. I store the different urls in the database and I these to a specific profession. Imagine the url is foo-listing.com, I will look up in the DB and will find that this is linked to the profession foo and I can list all the professionals for this profession.

Are there better solutions than this 2? If not which solution would be the best?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the differences in implementation for Foo and Bar professions. If you only want to store the professional's informations (name, phone number, address, etc), I'd go with 2. You'd have less code to maintain, updates would be easier.

If you want to have different applications, different informations stored, different layouts for Foo and Bar, I'd recommend having an engine that would be the core of your application. Then make a Foo and a Bar application that mount the engine and extend the functionality in different ways.

Comment: And should you go for a full or mountable engine?

Comment: I prefer to `isolate_namespace` for engines, but that's up to you.

Comment: So that would be mountable :)